# How to use a file with a .mac.opt extension?

Tags: macos, file

I am interested in running a programming language called MGS on my computer (obtainable here:  http://www.spatial-computing.org/mgs/start).  I am running Mavericks on mac.

The problem is that the mac executables download is a mac.opt file extension, and I have no idea what to do with it.  I can't find relevant information on this file extension anywhere on the internet.

Does anyone know what I might need to do to make this run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` says it is an executable:

```
$ file mgs64.mac.opt 
mgs64.mac.opt: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable
```

So, I'd just execute it in your Terminal. Open a Terminal window, `chmod +x` the program, and run it:

```
$ cd Downloads # or wherever you put the file
$ chmod +x mgs64.mac.opt
$ ./mgs64.mac.opt
```